# Javascript or PHP to get location and send it to me?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, gps, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript/PHP can I get GPS location and send it to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149233/javascript-php-can-i-get-gps-location-and-send-it-to-me)

Ok here's what I want:

I need something like a Javascript or PHP script to get a gps location from a visitor, and then secretly send it to me (I won't use this bad, it's for an website that prevents my iPhone from being stolen)

I want that if a thief opens the website (which I will webclip, name Safari and give the safari icon) I automatically get his location and he's redirected to google or something else

So basically like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
function GetLocation(location) {
    //Some script that sends the location secretly to me
}
{
    windows.location="http://google.com";
}
```

Can you help me please?

PS: I won't use this bad because it will only be on my iPhone, I know that there apps for it, but those cost money and I don't know if it's worth it.

UPDATE:

I found the following: I don't know what it really does but I guess it takes the location and sends it to location.php ???

```
function ajaxFunction() {
$.ajax({
  url:'location.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'lat='+lat+'&long='+long,
  success:function(d){
    console.log(d);
  },
  error(w,t,f){
    console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f);
  }
});
}
```

Now how do I make it redirect to google and put this on my website?

Comment: Why the hell do you post the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149233/javascript-php-can-i-get-gps-location-and-send-it-to-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the site and grant it access to the location, selecting "remember this decision" or whatever the option is called. Then the prompt will not appear in the future.

However, it might be a better idea to write an app for this.

Comment: That would be Safari, the fake Safari I was talking about before, is nothing less than a website saved to the homescreen, with Safari's icon and I would name it Safari.

So I'll hide the actual app in a folder, a thief thinks he sees the "Safari" and opens it so I get his location.

Comment: Yes, and this website would have to contain the JavaScript code using the html5 geolocation api. However, since users need to confirm it you need to confirm it so the prompt will not appear when your thief opens that page.

Comment: I've set up my phone that Safari always can use the location services and that it can't be changed without a code

Comment: Ugh, bad idea. But well then you just need to access the geolocation api and use AJAX to forward it to your server before redirecting e.g. to google.

Comment: I AM A 13 YEAR OLD BOY WHAT DID YOU EXPECT???

no seriously how do I do that?

Comment: Then go out and play with your friends. Or learn how to lookup information instead of always asking others.

Comment: I know nothing about AJAX... It looks like Math...

Comment: No... I swear I'm not... I jst don't want my device to get stolen because that did happen yesterday to my friend , I used iCloud to track it back, and it got me thinking. I just want to make a webpage that gets his location and sends it secretly and he won't even know...

Comment: So you want to snoop on your friend....

Comment: No, his iPod got stolen so he logged in on my device so he could send messages to it and so he got it back, what I'm trying to do here is just make a thief opening "Safari" and I get his location, it will only work on my device...